# Prolog query with the use of conditional cut

Tags: prolog

Iv'e been having problems with a prolog query that has some conditions hard to understand at first glance.

```
sameSum([L], V) :- !, sumlist(L,V). 
sameSum([L|R], V) :- sumlist(L,V),sameSum(R,V). 
sumlist([H],H) :- !.
sumlist([X|R],V) :- sumlist(R,Z), V is X+Z.
```

The query that is asked to be evaluated is:

```
?-sameSum([[6,7,2], [1,5,9], [8,3,4]], V). 
?-sameSum([[6,4,1,2], [1,12], [8,5]], V). 
?-sameSum([[6,7], [1,12], [8,5]], 13). 
?-sameSum([],V).
```

Thank you in advance for the big help.

Comment: What problem are you  facing? Shouldn't the empty list satisfy the `sameSum` predicate? After all, you can say that all the sublists (there are no sublists), have the same sum.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need for any cuts here, instead:

```
sameSum([], _V). 
sameSum([L|R], V) :-
   % L = [_|_],     % maybe 
   sumlist(L,V),
   sameSum(R,V). 

sumlist([],0).
sumlist([X|R],V) :-
   sumlist(R,Z),
   V is X+Z.
```

Note that your original definition failed for the last case you gave.

Comment: thanks a lot for the help! If I can ask, why in the original the last query was wrong?

Comment: `[]` was not considered.

Comment: Then check the answer!

Comment: oh sorry, I'm new here and I didn't know it